# Why do coliform bacteria smell so bad?

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture, sensation, ecoli, odour

I have done multiple cultures of *E. coli* bacteria and related species over the course of my education. Almost every time, they had this revolting smell. However, other organisms used for genetics experiments (eg. *Saccharomyces cerevisiae*) rarely have a bad scent, if a scent whatsoever. My question is, what is it about the coliform metabolism that produces such a pungent and revolting odor? Any and all answers are appreciated.

Comment: I'll note that "revolting" is a characteristic of the owner of the nose, not the producer of the scent chemicals; perhaps the nose owning organism evolved an aversion to those chemicals for some reason.

Comment: xD Well I guess it is, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*E. coli* and other bacteria [metabolize tryptophan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole_test) into odoriferous [skatole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skatole) and other [indole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole) compounds.

If you're culturing these organisms in medium that contains tryptophan, that may be what you're smelling.

Comment: Ah, Skatole! That makes sense. Thank you for your answer!